# How to setOnClickListener for AlertDialog with custom setView?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dialog, alert

i am showing an AlertDialog OnClickListener from Activity:

```
fav_btn.setOnClickListener {
        if(token.equals("false")){
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            val optionDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this).create()
            builder.setView(R.layout.alert_reg)
    
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes) { dialog, which ->
                val intent = Intent(this, SignupActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }

            builder.setNeutralButton(android.R.string.no) { dialog, which ->
                optionDialog.dismiss()
            }

            builder.show()

        }
        else{
            if (isFavourite)deleteFavorite(eventId)
            else postFavImage(eventId)
        }
    }
```

this is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="16dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Assalamualaikum Qalbies"
        android:textSize="19dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:textColor="#AC6AA6"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:textColor="#1AB7B8"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:text="To continue, please"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:textColor="#4C4F4F"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cancel_reg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:backgroundTint="#F3F3F3"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:textColor="#7D7D7D"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/confirmation_reg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:backgroundTint="#1AB7B8"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:text="Sign-Up"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

so far everything is working fine but I want to set the textviews "cancel_reg" and "confirmation_reg" rather than "setPositiveButton" and "setNeutralButton"

I tried to do this in the activity:

```
fav_btn.setOnClickListener {
        if(token.equals("false")){
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            val optionDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this).create()
            builder.setView(R.layout.alert_reg)
            val goreg = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.confirmation_reg)
            val cancel = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.cancel_reg)
            goreg?.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(this, SignupActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            cancel?.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(this, SignupActivity::class.java)
                optionDialog.dismiss()
            }
            builder.show()
        }
        else {
            if (isFavourite)deleteFavorite(eventId)
            else postFavImage(eventId)
        }
    }
```

i tried to delete "setPositiveButton" and "setNeutralButton" and replace them with Textviews "confirmation_reg" and "cancel_reg" from the view but i can't click them

am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need to call `findViewById` on the `AlertDialog`'s `View`

currently its being called on your `Activity` or `Fragment`. to fix this update your dialog creation code as following

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())

// Inflate the XML with layout inflator and keep a reference to find TextView's
val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_reg, null)
builder.setView(dialogView)

// Find TextView's using the dialogView
val goreg = dialogView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.confirmation_reg)
val cancel = dialogView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.cancel_reg)

goreg?.setOnClickListener {
    // Do something
}
cancel?.setOnClickListener {
    // Do something
}
builder.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, its working now in the Activity but i have the same AlertDialog in adapter for another purpose and i can't use inflate for this "val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_reg, null)"

Comment: You will have to get the layoutInflator as `val layoutInflator = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflator`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting clickable attribute to true in xml.

Comment: i tried that already, nothing happen, still can't click it